# Django: Running dumpdata command programmatically fails

Tags: django, encoding

I want to run django's `dumpdata` command programmatically, however

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('dumpdata', 'asdf', indent=2, output=filePath)
```

fails with `Unable to serialize database: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xdf' in position 83: ordinal not in range(128)`.

running `python3 manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 --output=dump.json.gz asdf` from the command line works fine though!

why won't it work with `call_command()`?

---

- python version: `3.6.9`
- django version: `3.2.13`
- `$LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`
- `$LC_ALL` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`
- `$LC_CTYPE` is set to `UTF-8`

Comment: Does filePath equal 'dump.json.gz', although I can't see how that would matter.

Comment: I might be convinced that you have found a Django bug. Especially if there's nothing at all in the error traceback that isn't in a Django-supplied module.

Answer (score 0):

**solution:**
had to update the webserver configuration to use the correct locale. (in my case editing `/etc/apache2/envvars` to use the default system locale.)